# Basic .text() not working. Am I insane?

Tags: jquery

I feel insane. I've been trying to figure out why this thing I've done a million times isn't working. First, here's the html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/property-info.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="property-container" class="main-container">
        <h2 id="propertyinfo-address"></h2>         
    </div>
</body>
```

and here's property-info.js:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    //get the property
   var propID = getQueryStringValue("propID");
   $.get( 'php/getProperty.php', {'propertyID': propID}, function(json) {
       $.each(json, function(i, property) {
            $("#propertyinfo-address").text(property.propAddress);
       })
   }, "json");    
});
```

Everything runs without error. The text just doesn't show up in the h2. I've console.logged all the values to be sure they are being set properly. I've even copied this code to fiddle and gotten it to run (minus the php). I have several other pages with similar code that works fine. I've tried pointing to different jQuery library links. It just doesn't work. I feel like someone is playing a trick on me. Someone please tell me what my stupid error is. :)

Comment: So if you console.log property.propAddress it is the correct value?

Comment: @Chris - yes, property.propAddress shows up fine in the console. That's what's making me insane. It's simple the .text() line that isn't working. Everything else is.

Comment: Give us the jsfiddle

Comment: @5PalmTechnique This might be stupid, but try using Text() instead of text() and see if it works? If all else fails just use .html() - that will work. If it doesn't then you know it is something else like your jquery file or something

Comment: Try removing the quotes from `$("document")`

Comment: @EricGuan For the `.ready` it does not really matter what you place between the brackets as long as you don't wan't to target a document that is different to the one where jQuery is loaded in. But yes it would be better to use `$(document)`.

Comment: You can also make sure that there is only 1 element with that id, if there are more it could be breaking your code

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but no luck. "s off document made no change. Capital Text tripped an error. I don't have the fiddle any more, unfortunately. jQuery.text() also had no effect. The H2 is the only one with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

Just a debugging hint, try `.fail` function on $.get function you have to make sure your php file is returning success and not an error, instead.

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "example.php", function() {
     alert( "success" );
}).fail(function() {
     alert( "error" );
});
```

I hope you can sort it out.

Comment: Thanks, Mahsa. I'm sure the php is working because I was able to display the data via console after the get. It just won't work in that one line. :-\ I also added `.done(function(json) {
  console.log(json);
 })
 .fail(function(json){
  console.log(json);
 });  ` and it returns done.

Comment: Anther time I had an issue that was related to jquery versioning, but I do not think it is you case as you said you have tried it out, so please use the `debugger;` in your code to see line by line or set a breakpoint in your `each` function using firebug, to see really what are the values you receive and if your `text` function is getting called with some value and not `null`. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it *was* working. There was some css that was displaying it off screen. Guess I'm not insane after all. Sorry for wasting everyone's time!